# How do I make an ad hover on page?

Tags: css

I'm talking about some of those websites with "Twitter" or "Feedback" hovering near the scroll bar or on the bottom of a page. I understand that it's a type of CSS but unsure about which.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.something {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  bottom:10px;
  right: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

PS: Get firefox and firebug.

You can right-click anything you see and look at the css for it right there.
http://getfirebug.com

Comment: No prob!  I use it every day.  It's a REAL life saver.

Answer (score 0):

You need `position: fixed` and `bottom: 0`.
`position: fixed` will fix it in the viewport, regardless of the scrollbar.